# Jquery auto complete box result is not showing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jquery autocomplete box in bootstrap modal. I am getting suggested data when i inspect it but it is not showing on page.
I am sorry i am new here , suggestion needed

Comment: Please add snippet of code so anyone can check and find the error for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the autocomplete in a bootstrap modal, the modal is most likely displaying in front of the autocomplete element. Try adding CSS that assigns a high z-index to test if this is what is occurring.

Maybe something like this:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
     z-index: 1050 !important;
}
```

Try different z-index values. If you are seeing it in the inspector it sounds like it is functioning correctly, the modal is just displaying in front.